# I want to improve my search performance mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to improve my search performance. I want to search the user against the services and specialty. user in listed as per the filter applied either by specialty or by services or can be both.There are 5 tables i want to get the data from all the table 
I have below table structure

```
1) users            :- id ,first_name,last_name 
2) users_services   :- id ,user_id,service_id
3) users_speciality :- id,user_id,specility_id
4) mst_services     :- id,name
5) mst_speciality   :- id,name
```

I have used this query to get the result and it works fine.

```
select  u.id,first_name,last_name,location,services.name as service_name,speciality.name as specility_name from users as u 

inner join  users_services  on u.id =users_services.user_id

Inner join mst_services as services on  services.id=users_services.service_id

inner join  users_speciality  on u.id =users_speciality.user_id
Inner join mst_speciality as speciality on  speciality.id=users_speciality.service_id WHERE speciality.name ="specificity one"
```

as per the normalization it seems correct.But when data is more than 1,00,000 that time joining too many table causes may create problem.
what should i do for filter the user according to services and specialty ?

Comment: Your query is fine. You can create indexes on user_id,service_id and specility_id in order to try and speed the query up

Comment: is it better if I create one more table called user_filter? in that table i will create 4 column id(PK), user_id(FK),specialty and services  these two column will hold th comma separated  value. and my query will be only on single table. Is this better option

Comment: Don't mess up the clean database design by using comma-separated values in columns.

Comment: all table will remain same but only one additional table which will only used for searching purpose

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ?

```
SELECT users.id,first_name,last_name, mst_services.name as service, mst_speciality.name AS speciality
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_services ON users.id = users_services.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_speciality ON users.id = users_speciality.user_id
LEFT JOIN mst_services ON service_id = mst_services.id
LEFT JOIN mst_speciality ON speciality_id = mst_speciality.id
WHERE users.id IN
(SELECT user_id FROM users_services
WHERE service_id = (SELECT id FROM mst_services WHERE name = "service one")
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id FROM users_speciality
WHERE speciality_id = (SELECT id FROM mst_speciality WHERE name = "spercial one"))
ORDER BY first_name,last_name,service,speciality
```